# Power on after power failure iMac 2019 with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mac, power-supply

Hi i just installed ubuntu on an iMac 19.1 and discovered that after a power failure it does not come back as it did when it had macos.

Looking around for solutions i saw several posts about using `setpci` with the correct registers based on the chip datasheet.

I tried to follow this procedure but from the output of `lspci` my chipset is `Intel Q370` and from the datasheet the important register would be 0x1020 however `setpci` returns out of range when i try to modify said register.

Then my question would be if is there a way to set the auto-poweron after power failure.

Comment: On a PC, auto-power on is a BIOS function. Given Mac's more integrated design, I'm guessing the normal auto power on behavior is baked into Mac OS, so you'll need some utility in Ubuntu that mimics this, if it is possible.